# Формат дату в Jackson Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, дата, format

Ко мне приходит время в таком виде: `"2017-12-04T15:45:11.635Z"`.

Для преобразование в `Date` ставлю такую аннотацию над соответствующим полем:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")`

На что получаю такую ошибку:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1512388174163,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException",
    "message": "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class ru.something.api.domain.AwesomeObject] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]",
    "path": "/consent/test"
}
```

Как формат необходимо указать для правильной десериализации времени?

Comment: а какой формат вам надо?

Comment: @RomanC мне надо подобрать формат под строку `2017-12-04T15:45:11.635Z`

Comment: Такой формат парсится под стринг, джаксон не может писать в таком формате.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы затолкать данную строку в переменную, нужно использовать такой паттерн
String s = "2017-12-04T15:45:11.635Z";
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));

Он же стандарт
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);

А вообще в частном случае для присвоения переменной переменно типа ZonedDateTime  можно вообще без паттернов
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s);

Обратите внимание, что используется именно ZonedDateTime , потому как переменных типа Date довольно много в разных пакетах, не факт , что она предназначена для хранения не только даты , а и времени да еще и с часовым поясом.
Посему мой совет - распарсите сначала в переменную ZonedDateTime , а там уже достаточно методов из коробки для конвертации куда угодно, если, конечно, это вообще нужно